# I would like to detect the first and last column containing a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.
I would like to detect the first and last column containing the value "FMD 1991", because I need to copy paste the value of each cells below cells containing the "FMD 1991 value" in a destination sheet.

Here's what I've done

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim FMD91 As String
Dim FMD97 As String
Dim FMD13 As String
Dim IECMIL As String
Dim MIL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim firstcol
Dim finalcol As Integer

FMD91 = "FMD 1991"


Worksheets("FailureModeDistribution_FMD").Select
firstcol = Find(what:="FMD 1991", lookat:=xlWhole, searchorders:=xlByColumns)
finalcol = Find(what:="FDM 1991", lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)



For i = 2 To finalcol
If Cells(2, i) = FMD91 Then
    Range(Cells(2, i)).Copy 
    FeuilleDonnees.Select
    Range("A2").End(xlToRight).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

May someone help me with that please?

Comment: You need to specify the range for the `Find` function

Comment: Should this "FMD 1991" be found anywhere on the sheet, or in the Headers row? Is "FMD 1991" the value of the cell, or part of the cell value string?

Comment: The value "FMD 1991" is only in the first row. I'd like to code something like : – detect the first column where "FMD 1991" appears, detect the last one containing the same value, copy the value below each cells containing the value "FMD 1991" and paste it somewhere else.

Comment: In addition to Teamothy's comment above, `firstcol = ` and `finalcol = ` are returning ranges? then should begin with `Set` like `Set firstcol = Range.Find(` .. [Refer this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: You can do this with array formula, `SMALL(IF($A$1:$H$1="FMD 1991",COLUMN($A$1:$H$1)),1)` and `LARGE(IF($A$1:$H$1="FMD 1991",COLUMN($A$1:$H$1)),1)`  and to retrieve the value `INDEX($A$1:$H$2,2,SMALL(IF($A$1:$H$1="A",COLUMN($A$1:$H$1)),1))` for example.

Comment: When you say ** first and last column containing the value "FMD 1991"** should we understand that there are more occurrences and the code must select the first and the last? Or only two, and the last should be the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It assumes that there can be more occurrences of the string to be searched for. If only two, the code can be simplified, replacing the iteration with a single code line:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_ClickSSS()
Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, FMD91 As String, firstRng As Range
Dim lastRng As Range, mtch, prevMtch, i As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet  'Worksheets("FailureModeDistribution_FMD")
Set shDest = sh.Next 'Use your destination sheet (FeuilleDonnees)
FMD91 = "FMD 1991"
mtch = Application.match(FMD91, sh.rows("1:1"), 0)

If IsError(mtch) Then
    MsgBox "No any match for " & FMD91 & " in the first row...": Exit Sub
Else
    prevMtch = mtch
End If
Set firstRng = sh.Range(sh.cells(2, mtch), sh.cells(sh.rows.count, mtch).End(xlUp)) 'set the first range to be copyed

For i = mtch To sh.UsedRange.Columns.count 'iterate between the rest of columns (in case of more occurrences):
    mtch = Application.match(FMD91, sh.Range(sh.cells(1, prevMtch + 1), sh.cells(1, sh.UsedRange.Columns.count)), 0)
    If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 'set all occurences as the last range to be copied
        Set lastRng = sh.Range(sh.cells(2, mtch + prevMtch), sh.cells(sh.rows.count, mtch + prevMtch).End(xlUp))
       prevMtch = prevMtch + mtch
    Else
        Exit For 'exit the loop and use the last set lastRng
    End If
Next i
 If lastRng Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No secong match for " & FMD91 & " could be found in the first row...": Exit Sub
'copying the ranges:
firstRng.Copy: shDest.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
lastRng.Copy: shDest.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```

Please, take care of using **your real sheets** to set `sh` and `shDest`. I used `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveSheet.Next` only to test the above code.

If only two occurrences of the string to be searched for, please state it and I will simplify the code. It will work with only two occurrences, too. If only one may exist, it can also be adapted to process only that one.

It will return in the next empty column of `shDest`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I took many things in your code and made some modification, it helped me a lot!

Comment: @SuperNova So, I should understand that it does not answer your question... Can you explain what has been stated in your question and the above code did not solve it?